# How to calculate the following infinite sum?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Let $x$ be a real number, $x \not= 1$ and $S = x + x^2 + x^3+...$

Then $xS = S - x$  and from this we get that $S = \frac{x}{1 - x}$

This does not hold true for example when $x \gt 1$

My question is the following:
Where is the mistake I made?

Comment: How exactly did you get $xS = S - x$

Comment: By multiplying S with x you get x * S = x^2 + x^3 + ... Then adding x to both sides results in x * S + x = x + x^2 + x^3 +... Or in other words x * S + x = S and finally substracting x from both sides results in x * S = S - x.

Comment: $S$ certainly doesn't exist if $x\geq1$

Comment: What you have looks entirely correct $S = \frac {x}{1-x}$ when $|x|<1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your fallacy is that you assumed that $x*S +x =S$.

The reason you cannot argue that they are equal is because for $x \gt1$ , the series is diverging and each term is bigger than the previous. Hence the sum of these two series will never be equal.

But for $x \lt 1$ , the series is indeed converging and it is possible to assume the equation.

Hence, your equation makes sense for only diverging series , i.e $x \lt 1$

Comment: Last line: You mean "only converging series".. & $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because you need to have $S$ finite to write that equality. If $S=\pm\infty$ (which holds for $|x| \geq 1$), then that equation does not make sense.

Comment: When $x<-1$, the sum oscillates as well, so it's not $+\infty$.

Comment: So this means that any equation that has infinity on one of the sides does not make any sense?

Comment: @Botond you're right. I added it. Maybe it's not quite formally correct, but it should indicate, that the result is not finite

Comment: @MarcGrec right